# Why is element of 'for-of' loop undefined?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom

I'm trying to filter the displaying of objects in an array based on what a user types into a search box (in this example, by the property 'prev.author'). I'm using a 'for-of' loop. If you check my code, you can see that I put in checks to make sure the individual variable, prev, is defined.

When I run the code, both checks show it is defined. The 'value' variable is set to whatever the user types in the box, & it works. However, when I try to style the individual variable (prev), I get the error message "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (reading 'style')". How could this element, prev, be undefined? It seems like I defined it when initializing the loop. Any help would be much appreciated, as I've already spent a few hours on it.

```
for (const prev of displayedPrevs) {
     console.log(prev);
     console.log(prev.author);
     console.log(typeof prev.author);
     
     // First check to see if prev is defined returns 'defined'
     if (typeof prev === 'undefined') {
          console.log('undefined');
     } else {
          console.log('defined')
     }

     if (prev.author.toLowerCase().trim().includes(value)) {
          // Second check to see if prev is defined returns 'defined'
          if (typeof prev === 'undefined') {
               console.log('undefined');
          } else {
               console.log('defined');
          }

          console.log('yes');
          prev.style.display = 'block'; // error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read 
                                                   properties of undefined (reading 'style')"
     } else {
          console.log('no');
          prev.style.display = 'none'; // error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read 
                                          properties of undefined (reading 'style')"
     }
}
```

Comment: How do you get `displayedPrevs`? What is the output for `console.log(prev)`?

Comment: What is `prev` supposed to be? Some kind of DOM element which has an `author` property? Or an arbitrary JS object, in which case is the `style` property initialized properly??

Comment: `console.log(typeof prev.style)`

Comment: Geshode, displayedPrevs is an array containing objects, which contain information for previews of blog post. console.log(prev) outputs one of those objects.

Comment: if `prev` is not some sort of `HTMLElemenrt` then `prev.style` will likely be undefined

Comment: So, they are general JS objects and not HTMLElements? Do those objects have a style property?

Comment: @JaromandaX That logs undefined

Comment: @Geshode I think they are general JS Objects and not HTML elements, so I don't think they would have a style property. Is this where the problem lies?

Comment: Then that's the issue, isn't it - exactly what the error is telling you `style is undefined`

Comment: Yes, if you don't have the property, you can't use it.

Comment: @Geshode That is where the problem lies. For anyone reading, I will try posting my solution to this once I figure it out. Thanks to those who have helped so far.

Comment: If it helps, the assumption that there was a problem with `prev` being undefined was incorrect: _if `prev` had been undefined_, accessing `prev.author` would have thrown and the second check would never have been reached.

Comment: @EthanG. I think it important to distinguish between your problem (_my code isn't working_) and your question (_why am I seeing `undefined`_). You can already post the answer to your question (e.g. something like _I thought they were DOM elements, but they're just plain objects_). Also, I would suggest that how you resolve this in your code is of less interest for future readers (which is, after all, what StackOverflow was designed for -- creating a knowledge base of good questions and answers that future readers can reference).

Comment: @ZevSpitz Very good points. That was my first question here, so I'm thankful for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it, with the help of some in the comments. For anyone with this same issue, make sure you are trying to change, for example, the style.display property of actual DOM elements that exist in your HTML, not items that only exist in JS.